# download speed throttled by something in the hard-wire mix

Tags: networking, router, download, lan

Time Warner (now Spectrum) cable internet, paying for 300Mbs.  I am getting less than 100Mbs on my wired units.  Here's the scenario:

This is how I’ve got things connected: Desktops > Server closet Patch panel > NETGEAR ProSAFE JFS524 24-Port Fast Ethernet Rackmount Switch > LinkSys router WRT1900ACS > Arris Surfboard Modem

I’m getting less than 100Mbs download from my hardwired desktops (I pay for 300Mbs). Time Warner came out and tested the modem (direct to laptop) and got 283Mbs.  He determined it was the switch (I didn’t ask at the time how he determined that, my bad).  So I replaced the switch.  Same problem.  So I replaced the router.  Same problem.  (and, yes, every time I replace a unit in the line, I restart everything: modem, router, switch)

Now I’m at a loss.  At this point, my WiFi-connected peripherals get better download speeds! Even my cell phone is getting close to 180Mbs.

Can a patch panel reduce download speeds? That's the only piece of equipment in the mix that hasn't been replaced. Is there something else I should test?  Should I set everything on fire?  (j/k. sort of.)

Comment: Bad wiring (and that included a badly done patch panel) can reduce speed. But before you check that, please check if all wired network connections are using gigabit speeds. If they are down to 100Mbps speeds (either due to settings or due to cabling or due to a bad handshake) then 100Mbps is presisely what I would expect as speed.

(Check and add to the post using the [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1193018/edit) link).

Comment: Also, I just realised that I edited the `Netgear 24port 100gb` to `Netgear 24port 100Mb`. That is 100 megabit per second max on a port. Assuming that you did not really mean a 100gigabit/sec speed your problem is clear.  (not posting as an answer until you can confirm that the edit is correct).

Comment: You are correct, my copy and paste apparently got carried away.  It's a "NETGEAR ProSAFE JFS524 24-Port Fast Ethernet Rackmount Switch." Nube question: how do I check if "all wired network connections are using gigabit speeds."  The two that I use the most are desktops: one Windows, one OS X.  Admittedly, I don't recall ever going into the settings for these computers; I just "plugged and played."

Comment: @jmflint: you don't need to check. hennes has pointed out that your netgear switch is 10/100 (NOT gigabit, I googled it). therefore anything going through it is throttled. Luckily, your linksys appears to be 4x gigabit  ports with a 1x WAN gigabit. In the past it was not unusual for the WAN port to be 100 megabit, which could have been a bottleneck as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help -- you and Hennes are both awesome and I appreciate your time and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The speed issue is due to the [Netgear JFS524 24 switch](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/JFS524.aspx). It is not a problem with the switch, it is working as intended and a fast as the manufacturer designed it to work. Which is 100Mbit/sec. YOu can see that both on [its specification page at Netgear](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/JFS524.aspx)and in its description. (`Fast Ethernet` is from the era when 10Mbit/sec was normal and the new 100Mbit/sec was fast.)

Looking at it as a bandwidth issue you have:

```
ISP to Arris Surfboard Modem. (should be the max 300Mbit/sec)
  |
  |
  |  (cable)
  |
  |                         1xport facing the WAN max 1Gbit/sec
LinkSys router WRT1900ACS   dual band wireless (varies but up to 1.9Gbit/sec)
  |                         4xport facing the WAN max 1Gbit/sec
  |
  |  (cable)
  |
  |
NETGEAR ProSAFE JFS524       Max speed per port is 100Mbit. 
  |   |
  |   |
  |    \
  |     --- Desktop
Desktop
```

Since it is a bandwidth problem you can think of it as water pipes.

A 30 cm wide pipe feeds your surfboard.
The surfboard has 100cm pipe to the linksys.

The linksys has 100cm in pipe,
The linksys has four 100cm out pipes,
The linksys has a sprinkler with a 190cm feed pipe.  (wireless).

The 100cm output from the linksys connects to 10cm pipes on the netgear.
This limits thoughput.

Possible solutions:

1. Replace the neargear with a gigabit model.
2. Use cables directly from the Linksys (it has 4 ports, but location cq long cables may be an issue).
3. Possibly try to combine 4 ports on the Linksys and 4 ports on the netgear as one bonded 400Mbit/sec link. These kind of solutions do exits and the OpenWRT (linksys) should be able to support it. Getting the Neargear to work along might be a *challenge*.

Comment: Wow.  Thank you SO much!!  That was a tremendous amount of info (and more than was given to me by the person who recommended that OTHER switch).  I've returned the slow switch and ordered NETGEAR 24-Port Gigabit Ethernet Desktop/Rackmount Switch (GS324).  Should come today (thank you, Amazon), and I can't wait to install it and test! Thanks again!

Comment: Make sure that the desktop as also 1Gbit (almost guaranteed onless you have a very old desktop or an old laptop) and that you have proper cat5 or better cables. Else it will still negotiate down to lower speeds.

Comment: We have lift-off!!  I can't tell you the thrill as I watched the speedtest hit 350!! OMG.  Thank you again!